# In discord.js, reactionCollector doesn't stop after calling stop() method

Tags: node.js, events, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm working on a bot in discord.js and am currently trying to do the following:
By triggering a command named `tournament prepare`, the bot waits for user inputs with a `reactionCollector`, collecting the reactions of the users that want to participate to the tournament.

Later, when the user that started the tournament uses the command `tournament begin`, the bot should close the collector, and output a list with the names of the players that joined the event.

This is what I've tried:

```js
// initialise the collector
var collector = null;

if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}prepare`)) {
  message.channel.send('A message')
    .then(async function (message) {
      await message.react('⚔')

      const filter = (reaction, user) => {
        return reaction.emoji.name === '⚔' && user.id != 705462496646922311
      };
      collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter);
      collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
        // code here
      });
    })
    .catch(function() {
      message.channel.send('Error while adding the reaction. Try again')
    });

}

if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}begin`)) {
  if(collector == null) {
    message.channel.send('Error message');
    return;
  }

  collector.stop();
  collector.on('end', collected => {
    // code here
  });
}
```

Everything works fine until the end event.
The documentation says this about the `stop()` method: `Stops this collector and emits the end event.`

I'm sure that the collector is stopped after using the `stop()` method, because I've debugged it, but for some reasons the end event never gets called. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, that its because you first stop it and than connect the event, so it will not fire, because collector already ended.

Comment: That's the problem, stop() is supposed to call the 'end' event.

Comment: Yes, but look on your code, it will execute line by line and when you call the stop() command, there is still no event. Try changing the order of these two lines.

Comment: @Kyle, random offtopic tip: It will be good idea to mark this anser as solution :).

Comment: I think yes (except this problem). But, you can move the end event under the collect event, the second if statement in message collector collect event (and put it under the end event (after you move the end event)) and the collector variable declare where you are defining it.

Comment: I'm not clear about what you wrote, could you show me please?

Comment: This approach is good only, when you have 1 collector per time. If you want to make this working for more  servers, you need to create message collector and use it for collecting the second message, then, you can declare the reaction collector inside the event.

Comment: For second message, do you mean the one that contains 'A message'?

Comment: I mean ${prefix}begin message

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the location of the collector.stop()

```
collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
            // code here, your stop condition also goes here with collector.stop()
          });
collector.on('end', collected => {
    // code here
  });
}
```